# Unable to install Arduino 1.8.9 on raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: arduino

Im trying to install the arduino IDE on my raspi.
I am using the .tar from the website to get the last version (Linux Arm 64b) 
I tried from interface and from the terminal, in the opt or in the usr folder, I always get the same problem.
I see the icon, but nothing happens when I launch it.
In terminal I get this when i run sudo ./install

> Adding desktop shortcut, menu item and file associations for Arduino
>   IDE... rm: impossible de supprimer '/usr/local/bin/arduino': Aucun
>   fichier ou dossier de ce type Removing symlink failed. Hope that's OK.
>   If not then rerun as root with sudo.
>
> rm: impossible de supprimer '/usr/local/bin/arduino': Aucun fichier ou
>   dossier de ce type Removing symlink failed. Hope that's OK. If not
>   then rerun as root with sudo.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type = No file or folder of this type.  impossible de supprimer = impossible to delete. It's as if the tarball you d/l is trying to alter an existing install. Where did you find this package? Have you reached out to the author(s)? Did you try [this one?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/program-arduino-uno-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: `Linux Arm 64b` - although the pi3 (and pi2 now) CPU's are 64bit, they run in 32bit mode, unless you've specifically installed a 64 bit OS of course (which seems highly unlikely)

Answer (score 1):

Just download the **Linux ARM 32bits** version from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

All Raspbian OS are 32 bit.

See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/44813/3879 for comments on installing Arduino on the Pi (slightly outdated).

Comment: 32 bit is a version of the x86 architecture. like i said, raspberry pi runs an x64 architecture. 32 bit is the binary. Certain pis support 64 bit and 32 bit but architecture is completely different

Comment: @Krutav What part of **ARM** don't you understand?

Comment: `raspberry pi runs an x64 architecture` no, it doesn't

Answer (score -1):

It is completely possible to program an arduino from raspberry PI but, the version you are trying to install is a linux file that is for x86. The architecture of the Raspberry Pi is x64 architecture, so it needs a different program. Try running: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install arduino` and it will install arduino, from there, you can create programs. It will be in your application folder. I just tried and it seems to be working fine on a Pi2

Comment: **DO NOT** do this the version in the repository 1.0.5 is hopelessly out of date!

Comment: `the version you are trying to install is a linux file that is for x86` - no, OP is installing Arm 64bit in an arm 32bit OS - nothing to do with intel/amd architecture at all `Raspberry Pi is x64 architecture` no, it isn't, it's Arm 32 bit ... so you're wrong on both architecture and bits! You actually couldn't be further from correct than you are